# oracle SQL how to remove time from date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column named `StartDate` containing a date in this format: `03-03-2012 15:22`

What I need is to convert it to date. It should be looking like this: `DD/MM/YYYY`

What I have tried without success is:

```
select 
p1.PA_VALUE as StartDate,
p2.PA_VALUE as EndDate
from WP_Work p 
LEFT JOIN PARAMETER p1 on p1.WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p1.NAME = 'StartDate'
LEFT JOIN PARAMETER p2 on p2.WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p2.NAME = 'Date_To'
WHERE p.TYPE = 'EventManagement2'
AND TO_DATE(p1.PA_VALUE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= TO_DATE('25/10/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND TO_DATE(p2.PA_VALUE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE('26/10/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT1: the `PA_VALUE` column is: `VARCHAR2`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you convert your string to a date you need to match the date mask to the format in the string.  This includes a time element, which you need to remove with truncation:

```
select 
    p1.PA_VALUE as StartDate,
    p2.PA_VALUE as EndDate
from WP_Work p 
LEFT JOIN PARAMETER p1 on p1.WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p1.NAME = 'StartDate'
LEFT JOIN PARAMETER p2 on p2.WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p2.NAME = 'Date_To'
WHERE p.TYPE = 'EventManagement2'
AND trunc(TO_DATE(p1.PA_VALUE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')) >= TO_DATE('25/10/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND trunc(TO_DATE(p2.PA_VALUE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')) <= TO_DATE('26/10/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

---

Outside the scope of the question, but storing dates as strings is bad practice, and storing date times is even worse.

1. We need to convert the strings to dates in order to do any form of date processing (arithmetic, interval assessment, etc) on them
2. Strings offer no guarantees regarding format, so we run the risk of date corruption crashing our code. We can defend against this by employing `VALIDATE_CONVERSION()` (available since 12c, [find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html) ) but it's still a PITN
3. Using non-standard datatypes makes it harder to reason about the data model and the code we build over it.

Answer (score 71):

You can use [TRUNC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2127.htm) on DateTime to remove Time part of the DateTime. So your where clause can be:

```
AND TRUNC(p1.PA_VALUE) >= TO_DATE('25/10/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

> The TRUNCATE (datetime) function returns date with the time portion of
>   the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model.

Comment: here is what i got: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
            00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: To add to this: in Oracle, you can also use [Function Based Indexes](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_function_based_index_2.html), that can speed up using TRUNC, or any other function...

Comment: What is the Data type of PA_Value ? isn't it DateTime ?

Comment: it's VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), sorry I didn't checked it, as I saw the date/time content. Now it's going harder :(

Comment: @Slim, in that case you may change the DataType to DateTime, as it is always a bad idea to store date as string. If you can't change the Data type, then you have to cast your column to DateTime to use convert, or you may continue using your current SQL statement, as it is probably a better choice

Comment: But my current statement is not working... It's giving me this error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Comment: You may have specified the wrong format for the column `p1.PA_VALUE`. What is the value inside that column and do all the values have the same format ?

Comment: yes, all the values are in the same format **(dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)**

Comment: In that case you have to specify format including the time part as well, to convert it to date, and then you can use `TRUNC` to compare it against the Date part.

Answer (score 10):

We can use TRUNC function in Oracle DB. Here is an example.

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('01 Jan 2018 08:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) FROM DUAL
```

Output:
    1/1/2018

Comment: Oracle TRUNC function is slow, isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
SELECT to_char(p1.PA_VALUE,'DD/MM/YYYY') as StartDate,
       to_char(p2.PA_VALUE,'DD/MM/YYYY') as EndDate
   ...
```

Comment: This query returns varchars, not dates.

Comment: Date is a datatype, its look as a string determined by client and database TNS settings. Since OP wanted to date being formatted with the predetermined pattern the only way to do it is to convert to varchars. By the way, OP edited his question so my response is no longer applied.

Answer (score 1):

If your column with DATE datatype has value like below : -

value in column : 10-NOV-2005 06:31:00

Then, You can Use TRUNC function in select query to convert your date-time value to only date like - DD/MM/YYYY or DD-MON-YYYY

select TRUNC(column_1) from table1;

result : 10-NOV-2005

You will see above result - Provided that NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set as like below :-

Alter session NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Answer (score 0):

there is also extended usage like this:

```
  WITH dates AS (   
  SELECT date'2015-01-01' d FROM dual union   
  SELECT date'2015-01-10' d FROM dual union   
  SELECT date'2015-02-01' d FROM dual union   
  SELECT timestamp'2015-03-03 23:45:00' d FROM dual union   
  SELECT timestamp'2015-04-11 12:34:56' d FROM dual    
)   
SELECT d "Original Date",   
       trunc(d) "Nearest Day, Time Removed",   
       trunc(d, 'ww') "Nearest Week", 
       trunc(d, 'iw') "Start of Week",   
       trunc(d, 'mm') "Start of Month",   
       trunc(d, 'year') "Start of Year"   
FROM dates;
```

[Oracle Offical Help Page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79)