# I need to extract the birthda from a table, and I keep getting the time. I want to remove that. sqlplus

Tags: sqlplus, python-3.3

I am currently writing a DBMS program for a project for school.  I NEED TO EXTRACT the birthday of the person I search for in a query.  the column name is birthday, but when i do:

SELECT birthday from people, I get mm/dd/yyy and then i also get 00:00:00:
how do I get only the birthdate I input when i created the table, and not the time?

i do not want the current date, just the one in the table

Comment: possible duplicate of [oracle SQL how to remove time from date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135552/oracle-sql-how-to-remove-time-from-date)

Comment: that is different from what i am asking.  I do not want an entire query.  I need something I can use to extract only the date from the datetime in Sql in another query.

Comment: That question asks about retrieving only the date portion of a column (without the time), and the accepted answer shows exactly how to do so using `Trunc`. Read the linked question (and it's answer), please. I found it using `[oracle] select date without time`, which is exactly what you're asking to do here. You should not expect someone to write the exact statement for you. Answers may exist that provide the information if you read them and try to apply what they're saying to your own problem.