# Get only date without time in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this sql request to retrieve some data and I have this columd 'pa.fromdate' which returns a date and a time. How do I get it to return only date in 'DD.MM.YYYY' format. I've tried something like `trunc(to_date(pa.fromdate, 'MM.DD.YYYY'))`. Doesn't work. How can I do that?

```
SELECT pro.inscatid,
  t.epotypeid,
  t.paysum,
  t.note,
  pa.blankno,
  pa.blankseria,
  pa.signtime,
  pa.fromdate,
  ca.accnum,
  ou.name,
  cst.inn,
  pkg_customers.GETCUSTOMERFULLNAME(cst.id) cstfio
FROM epo_orders t
LEFT JOIN epo_orderdetails od
ON od.orderid      = t.id
AND od.iscanceldoc = -1
LEFT JOIN plc_Agree pa
ON pa.id = od.agreeid
LEFT JOIN pro_products pro
ON pro.id = pa.proid
LEFT JOIN nsk_transferdetails td
ON td.transferid = pa.transferid
AND td.orgtypeid = 4
LEFT JOIN cst_customers cst
ON cst.id = t.cstid
LEFT JOIN cst_cstaccounts ca
ON ca.id = t.cstaccid
LEFT JOIN nsk_orgunits ou
ON td.orgunitid    = ou.id
WHERE t.epotypeid IN (159,1010,169,175)
AND rownum         <20;
```

Comment: `to_char(pa.fromdate, 'MM.DD.YYYY')` - **NEVER** call `to_date()` on a value that is already a `DATE`

Comment: On a sidenote: Many outer joins. Are you really interested in orders without order details? Don't give the DBMS more work to do than necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oracle SQL how to remove time from date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135552/oracle-sql-how-to-remove-time-from-date)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Usually one would simply truncate the datetime with `TRUNC`:

```
TRUNC(pa.fromdate)
```

This removes the time part from the datetime, so you get the mere date. Then in your application layer, you would care about how to display it.

For example you have a GUI with a grid. The grid displays the dates according to the user's system settings (e.g. Windows region settings), but the grid knows it's dates and can sort accordingly. For this to happen, you'd fill the grid with *dates*, not with *strings* representing a date.

If you want a fixed string format (e.g. in order to write into a file), you can use `TO_CHAR` instead:

```
TO_CHAR(pa.fromdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the [`TRUNC()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79) doesn't really remove time, it sets it to midnight ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8dfa3c3d27f3eb3087fbce115746f12e)).

Comment: @Álvaro González: Yes, this is a good point. In Oracle there is no date data type, but only a datetime, which they inappropriately call `DATE`. So, yes, `TRUNC` merely sets the time to midnight and this is both considered a datetime at midnight and a date in Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `to_char(pa.fromdate, 'MM.DD.YYYY')`, and this will give you desired result

Answer (score 4):

don't use `to_date()` on date value column, use `to_char()` with mask, like this

```
    select 
    ......
        to_char(pa.fromdate,'MM.DD.YYYY') fromdate
    ......
from ....
where ....
```

Comment: Double negative. Does it imply, use `to_date()`?

Answer (score 1):

### try this

```
select pro.inscatid,
t.epotypeid,
t.paysum,
t.note,
pa.blankno,
pa.blankseria,
pa.signtime,
to_char(pa.fromdate,'MM.DD.YYYY')fromdate,
ca.accnum,
ou.name,
cst.inn,
pkg_customers.GETCUSTOMERFULLNAME(cst.id) cstfio 
 from
epo_orders t
left join epo_orderdetails od on od.orderid = t.id and od.iscanceldoc = -1
left join plc_Agree pa on pa.id = od.agreeid
left join pro_products pro on pro.id = pa.proid
left join nsk_transferdetails td on td.transferid = pa.transferid and td.orgtypeid = 4
left join cst_customers cst on cst.id = t.cstid
left join cst_cstaccounts ca on ca.id = t.cstaccid
left join nsk_orgunits ou on td.orgunitid = ou.id 
where t.epotypeid in (159,1010,169,175) and rownum<20
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT to_char(Column_name,'DD/MM/YYYY') Column_Name
FROM Table_Name

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't ad anything to the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks it does add value to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `to_char()` function for this. And you can use `trunc()` to solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

To get data for only date filter, use TRUNC in front of column name.

Like use TRUNC(table.column_name) = 'DD-MM-YYYY'

Example:
TRUNC(Employee.Joining_Time)= '01-JAN-2021'

Just use same format of date as per in the column used where you have full string of date concat time.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you suggesting to compare a date with a string? This is a very bad idea. If you want to compare with a fixed date, then use a date literal, e.g. `TRUNC(table.column_name) = DATE '2021-05-15'`.

Comment: His understanding looks like referring to object.property_name concept which is true.