# Convert datetime to UTC beginning of the day - Oracle db

Tags: sql, database, oracle

For example:

I've got datetime in Oracle database like: `18/08/21 13:51:23,420460500` (y/m/d) and I want convert to type: `18/08/20 22:00:00,000000000`.

Could you please let me know how can I do this?

I've tried `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC("MyDate")` but it does not work in that case.

Comment: What is exactly that you want to do? You're not changing your date format but just updating column value, am I right?

Comment: it would be good if you could also describe how you get from the first timestamp to the second. I do not understand the logic behind it

Comment: 22:00:00 is 10 PM, not the beginning of the day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135552/oracle-sql-how-to-remove-time-from-date

Answer (score 0):

From the format of your question, I'm assuming you have a `TIMESTAMP` value, since Oracle doesn't have a "datetime" data type. You can truncate the time component to midnight (the beginning of the day) with the [`TRUNC`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm) function, though it returns a `DATE` data type. I'm not sure where the 22:00 in your question is coming from.